# What can convolution layer without batch normalization and activation function contribute to models?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I recently saw some paper about stereo matching :

*End-to-End Learning of Geometry and Context for Deep Stereo Regression* [1]
https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017/papers/Kendall_End-To-End_Learning_of_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf

*End-to-End Learning for Omnidirectional
Stereo Matching with Uncertainty Prior* [2](which isn't free to see this paper. But the DL model is almost as same as Gc-net paper, except the model is for wide angle multi camera )

These papers are about stereo matching in computer vision area, The models in the papers are composed of Unary feature extraction + cost volume (As simple you can think it as concatenating 2 or more data's feature) + 3D convolution.

What I don't understand fully is in the Unary feature extraction part, the models have some 2D convolution layers with residual connection, and then after this there's a 2D convolution layer with no activation and batch normalization before cost volume part.

The gc-net [1]'s unary feature extraction works like

```
(1) 5x5 conv, 32 features, stride 2-> (2) 3x3 conv, 32 features -> (3) 3x3 conv, 32 features
(4) (1)-(3) residual connection
(5) (2), (3) repeat a few times with residual connection
(6) 3x3 conv, 32 features (no ReLu or BN)
```

What does this (6) convolution layer without activation and batch normalization contribute to the model?

In the 'End-to-End Learning for Omnidirectional Stereo Matching with Uncertainty Prior'[2] paper says that

> the last layer without the ReLU in the feature extraction part allows
> the network to distinguish between negative features and invisible
> areas, where the network is set to zero by the ReLU and warping
> operations, respectively.

But I can't understand how the layer without activation function and normalization contribute above things.

And in 3D convolution part of Gc-net [1] also has no-ReLu, or BN too. The paper says

> The network can also pre-scale the matching costs to control the
> peakiness (sometimes called temperature) of the normalized
> post-softmax probabilities (Figure 2). We explicitly omit
> batch normalization from the final convolution layer in the
> unary tower to allow the network to learn this from the data.

Which means 3D conv layer without BN helps 'softargmin' (or softargmax) function not to have multi-modal distribution. This thing I don't understand how the conv layer without activation and and normalization has such ability.